# How to remove the string/name with underline if it has not data or blank lines in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have data in a file where there are few names or strings marked underline but they do not have any data below it, rather they have space/blank line where as there also lines where there is data below underline.

How to print only those names/strings underlined which are having data following it?

Data file example:

```
toran
—————————————————————————


nscld
—————————————————————————


polkit
—————————————————————————


ganter
—————————————————————————
tcp        0      0 D
tcp        0      0 D
tcp        0      0 D

polkit
—————————————————————————
```

In above File I only need:

```
ganter
—————————————————————————
tcp        0      0 D
tcp        0      0 D
tcp        0      0 D
```

Tried below code but it did not works as expected as its unable to get  the string/name , only gets data.

```
patt_match = False
with open("tran", "r") as lb:
   for line in lb:
     if '—————————————————————————' in line:
         patt_match = False

     elif 'tcp' in line:
         patt_match = True
         line = line.strip()
         print(line)
```

Actual output:

```
tcp        0      0 D
tcp        0      0 D
tcp        0      0 D
```

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Please try something yourself, no matter how wrong, and we will help you fix it.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, i have added the trial code, please check the edit in my Question.

Comment: You never use the `pat_match` flag.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Close vote removed.

Comment: @reculseSoul Will there always be only 1 string with data below it or can there be multiple strings that have data under them?

Comment: @Flaming_Dorito, before the data there will be only one string/name including underline.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, thnx for your Kindness, What was the Close vote, Does that mean minus vote?

Comment: @reculseSoul. No. Five close votes means your question is put on hold for being inappropriate and no one can post answers.

Comment: @reculseSoul Thats not what I mean. Is something like this a possibility: https://pastebin.com/QLct0nHY Where you need to get the data with the title for both `nscld` and `ganter`

Comment: @Flaming_Dorito, yes the data pattern will like that only as you mentioned in pastebin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only determine if a heading needs to be printed after you get to a data line. This means that you need to retain the last heading in a variable, and print it before the first occurrence of a data line.

Here is a sample implementation that retains the last line of text. If the text is followed by a line containing `'—————————————————————————'`, it gets flagged as a heading line, otherwise it gets treated as a data line and the last heading is printed.

Since you mentioned in the comments that your data originates on Windows, I have added a line to strip any trailing carriage returns from your lines. This will work just fine with files that don't have them as well:

```
with open('tran', 'r') as f:
    prev_line = ''  # Not strictly necessary, but avoids some warnings
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\r')
        if '—————————————————————————' in line:
            heading = prev_line
        elif line.startswith('tcp'):
            if '—————————————————————————' in prev_line:
                print(heading)
                print(prev_line)
            print(line)
        prev_line = line
```

This will skip the newlines between sections, but you can include those with something like:

```
elif not line and prev_line.startswith('tcp'):
    print(line)
```

Here is an [IDEOne Link](https://ideone.com/lLKZOm) that demos the code with @Flaming_Dorito's example.

Comment: you code works but the output result have a blank line after each printed line.

Comment: @reculseSoul. Are you using a windows-generated text file on a Linux or Mac machine by some chance? The code I linked does not have any extra newlines in the output: https://ideone.com/lLKZOm

Comment: I'm on a linux OS that's RedHat.

Comment: @reculseSoul. And your output probably contains the Windows `\r\n` line separator characters, so you end up with extra newlines. I'll add an edit for that momentarily.

Comment: i have used `line = line.strip()` to chop any Blank lines and placed a Blank line Just before the header to get the blank line as a Separator between the outputs. I have Marked the answer as well. thnx for your guidance again.

Comment: @reculseSoul. I saw your suggested edit and I have to point out that it inserts a newline before the first header. My version  handles Windows-generated files correctly and inserts blank lines after data sections properly.

Comment: Mad Physicist, I don't have windows generated File , Its created on the Linux machine.

Comment: Then where are the extra newlines coming from? Iterating over a file with a `for` loop strips the newlines...

Comment: That's what my concern is , i'm not able to get that really.

Comment: @reculseSoul. Try to look at how your file is generated. It may be coming from there. Because the data that you show here does not have that problem.

Comment: Glad it helped. We were all begginers once, and I'm happy to help you get on with it if as long as you put in the work yourself :)